# Check if generic parameter of a class implements an interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I have a following generic class:

```
public class SearchResult<T>
{
    public int ResultCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Result { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `Bird` class, which implements `IFlyble` interface:

```
public class Bird : IFlyable
{
    public void Fly() {}
}

public interface IFlyable
{
    void Fly();
}
```

I also have a variable `res` of type `object`.
How do I check if `res` is a `SearchResult<IFlyable>` ?

I tryied this way:

```
if (res.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SearchResult<IFlyable>)))
{
    ///
}
```

And this way:

```
if(res is SearchResult<IFlyable>)
{
    ///
}
```

But it does not seems to work.

Comment: @maccettura res is an `object` and does not have a `Result`  property.

Comment: @mjwills I want to check if particular `object` is a `SearchResult<Flyable>`

Comment: What is the actual concrete type of `res`?  Is it `object res = new SearchResult<IFlyable>()` or is it actually `object res = new SearchResult<Bird>()`.

Comment: On another note if you have to do type checking when using generics then it's very likely that you have made a bad design decision, so explaining why you want to do this might allow us to suggest another approach.

Comment: @juharr `object res = new SearchResult<Bird>()`

Comment: Why are your properties settable? If I have a `SearchResult<Bird>` in hand, why should I be allowed to set the result count to -100, say?

Comment: @EricLippert I agree, you probably should not be allowed to mutate them, but I do not see how it is relevant to the question. Why do you find it important in the context of that particular question ?

Comment: That's like asking Mozart why he's trying to teach you how to play :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem you are having is probably due to the fact that `SearchResult<Bird>` is *not convertible* to `SearchResult<IFlyable>` because `SearchResult<T>` is invariant in `T`.

C# only admits generic type variance in interfaces and delegates. You need to define an `ISearchResult<>` interface that is covariant in its generic type.

In your case, if it’s acceptable that `T` is only used as an output you could define such interface as follows:

```
public interface ISearchResult<out T>
{
     int ResultCount { get; }
     IEnumerable<T> Result { get; }
}
```

And now a `ISearchResult<Bird>` is a `ISearchResult<IFlyable>` because you’ve given the compiler enough information so that it can verify that the conversion is in fact safe.

Comment: very nice explanation (+1) from me.

Comment: To reiterate InBetween's answer with in less technical terms: Suppose `out` was not required.  Then C# would allow you to convert `IList<Bird>` to `IList<IFlyable>`, which would allow you to add an `Airplane` to an `IList<Flyable>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this using reflection, which also works and no need to create another interface.

```
static void Main()
{
    var sr = new SearchResult<Bird>();
    Console.WriteLine(IsSearchResultIFlyable(sr.GetType())
        ? "sr is SearchResult<IFlyable>"
        : "sr is Not SearchResult<IFlyable>");

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static bool IsSearchResultIFlyable(Type t)
{
    if (!t.IsGenericType) return false;
    if (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(SearchResult<>)) return false;

    var gr = t.GetGenericArguments();
    return gr.Length == 1 && typeof(IFlyable).IsAssignableFrom(gr[0]);
}
```